# How to get user role claims in postman from Azure active directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a few users added to my Azure AD account, I would like to get the roles and user information on these users by calling an Azure API from Postman in the form of claims. I tried calling the following URL with the parameters as :

https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantId/oauth2/token

Body: 
grant_type : password, 
client_id : client id, 
client secret : client secret

I receive the access_token in the encoded format in the response, When I decode it on https://jwt.io/ I see the decoded data, but there's no user roles in the access_token.

I would like to get the user information and the roles in the form of claims in same response.

What approach would I need to take on this ?

Comment: Do you mean Azure AD directory roles? Those aren't included in tokens.

Comment: I mean, the user info and the roles(s) in which the user is inside Azure AD

Comment: If you mean directory roles like Global Administrator, those are not returned in tokens. They need to be queried from MS Graph API separately.

Comment: Can't the user info and roles be retrieved in the same response ?

Comment: That you might be able to do. If you call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id-here?$expand=memberOf` it might work. That'd return you the user info + groups and directory roles they are in. Expands have some limits though so you might need to call memberOf separately if a user has a lot of groups (or if the expand doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

If the role you mentioned refers to directory role, the answer is no, it won't be returned in the token. Just like juunas said, you can call [graph api to get directory role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0) information.

[image]

If the role you mentioned refers to application role, the answer is yes, you can get the role information in id_token. The **prerequisite** is that you have [assigned some roles to the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal).

[image]

Here are the detailed steps. You can also refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

1. edit the manifest to add some custom roles.

[image]

Something like this.

```
{
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "Test",
      "id": "c200e304-fff3-49f1-a4df-e406741ea680",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Bla bla",
      "value": "test"
    }
```

2.[assign users to roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles).
Click Enterprise applications->All applications->
[image]

Click your application->click Users and groups->click Add user
[image]

role assign.

[image]

Here is the request to get id_token.
[image]

You will find the roles in id_token.
[image]

Comment: I am have got the id_token, but there's no roles in it : 

{
  "aud": "2bbda19c-875b-4fb0-b474-b35021710d3d",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/4064cbd4-e8bf-40f6-abd8-3577d21c5d1a/",
  "iat": 1554377173,
  "nbf": 1554377,
  "exp": 155438,
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "family_name": "<famname>",
  "given_name": "<gname>",
  "ipaddr": "<IPAddress>",
  "name": "<usrname>",
  "oid": "656464-d3ac-4017-9ad3",
  "sub": "oaLnQo7uM9auYT0XmR_3Gpg8yoYrGsTFGA1Rd39JijQ",
  "tid": "4064cbd4-e8bf-40f6-abd8-3577d21c5d1a",
  "unique_name": "<uniquename>",
  "upn": "<upn>",
  "ver": "1.0"
}

Comment: @MukkuP So you are going to get the application role of the user, right? If so, you need to add some custom roles in the manifest first, then assign the roles to the user. I have updated my answer with more details regarding this.

Comment: @MukkuP If you have any further questions regarding this, just let me know. If you have no further concerns, please make it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: I got the application role in the id_token, I also got the user info by calling the url : 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id-here?$expand=memberOf

Comment: I got the application role in the id_token, I also got the user info by calling the url : 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user-id-here?$expand=memberOf
But there's no directory role information in it, see below response :

Comment: {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity",
    "businessPhones": [],
    "displayName": "<username>",
    "givenName": "<givenname>",
    "jobTitle": null,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null,
    "surname": "<surname>",
    "userPrincipalName": "<userPrincipalName>",
    "id": "61237043-d3ac-4017-65464-546566"
}

Comment: @MukkuP You should use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/memberOf which provided in my answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0  Not that one junnas provided.

Comment: I could retrieve the roles of the user now, Is it possible to access the of a guest user who have been added to AD, if yes, how ?

Comment: @MukkuP If you call the graph api to get the directory role for the user, the answer is yes. Just get the token by using client_credentials. As far as I know, we can not get the application role for the guest user